# Drupal filter view on taxonomy term and user role

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a rather basic question but I can not wrap my mind around how to solve it "nice".
I have a node type that contains calendar info, I use views to get the month-view rendered nice and all is good so far.
Next thing was to make the calendar view also contain nodes of type "group_xyz" but only display these events when a user is logged in I managed to do that with filtering using a couple of lines PHP to get user id and node type, but already here it didnt feel like a real drupalish solution...

To my problem, we would like to limit the display of calendar posts depending on the user role and a taxonomy term used in the node.

So the node has a taxonomy term reference "visibility_to" lets say one of (All, Internal, Administrators) set.
The user can be either guest, logged in user or administrator.

Now I would like to find a nice way to filter like this: Display the item IF node-type is calendar AND ( (visibility_to == "All") OR ( (visibility_to == "Internal") AND (role=="administrator" OR role == "logged_in") OR (visisbility_to == "Administrators" AND role =="administrator"))

I think you get the point... I think I could manage to hard code this in PHP but the day when we add new roles, new taxonomy terms I would rather have all this configured using the admin interface...

Any help and/or suggestions is appreciated.
Also posted in drupal forums at: http://drupal.org/node/1879238

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's how I'd do it in a 'Drupalish' way:

1. In your 'visibility' vocabulary, I'd add a **field that is a role reference** (in Drupal 7 terms can have their own fields -- yay!).  You have to download and enable the [Role Reference module](http://drupal.org/project/rolereference) to be able to set up this type of field.  For my example, I will call the term's role-reference field 'Visibility role'
2. Now modify all your visibility terms and fill in the newly created role field for each, essentially setting which role is applicable to which term.  I suppose you could just have a role reference directly on the node, rather than behind the term, but that's up to you
3. In your view, add the relationship 'Content:visibility' or whatever that term is called
4. Finally, add a contextual filter that will compare the role in the 'visibility' term to the current user's role.  Only after you've added the above relationship, will the field 'Visibility role' pop-up in the list of available contextual filters.  Select that as your contextual filter.  Choose 'Provide default value' and 'PHP code' as your options.  ***Type in the following php code to compare the roles associated with the node's term with the role of the current user***:

   ```
   global $user;

   $current_roles = "";
   foreach ($user->roles as $key => $val) {
     $current_roles .= $key;
     if ($val != end($user->roles)){ // If not last item, add a '+' which treats these as an or
       $current_roles .= '+';
     }
   } 

   return($current_roles);
   ```

*** Finally, make sure you expand the 'More' option under the contextual filter and select to allow multiple values for this filter.

Try it out and let us know if this works for you!!  I tested it out and it seems to work for me.

Comment: Hi, did a quick test and it seems to work. However I get multiple entries in the calendar... havent had time to test if it is because of multiple terms referenced or multiple roles on the same user...

A quick test by disabling "allow multiple values for this filter" seems to get rid of the duplicates/triplets...

Comment: Followup question: for all the calendar entries earlier that does not have a term specified / role specified. What is the easiest way to set a new default value for those? Or could one handle it in the contextual filter?

Comment: I'm so glad it worked!! It took a little while to figure out!  For your follow-up: I haven't used it, but I'd try the following module for bulk updates to entities: http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations.

Comment: Havent had time to test this further. But it seems to work and is the best solution so far so I'm gonna accept this. Thx.